# Как лучше делать реализацию покупок?

Tags: android, in-app-purchases

Для реализации покупок в Android можно использовать [IabHelper](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/in-app-billing/purchase-iab-products.html), а можно использовать непосредственно [IInAppBillingService](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html).
Какой способ будет более правильным? Или между ними по функционалу и качеству нет разницы?

Не пойму я почему вопрос минусуют, можно же ответ дать, в чем моя ошибка.

Я почему спрашиваю, в одном проекте использовал первый способ, в итоге много ошибок с покупкой у пользователей, а у меня все норм работает (пытаюсь фиксить), во втором - второй способ (в нем пока не ясно на сколько хорошо работает). Да и в общем говорят, что с покупками всегда проблемы били.

Comment: ответ на ваш вопрос зависит от мнения, по этому он является оффтопом

Comment: @metalurgus То есть фактической разницы нет, можно и через IabHelper сделать хорошо и через IInAppBillingService? И поправил вопрос, возможно не правильно выразился.

Comment: "разницицы" - поправьте еще

Answer (score 1):

А почему не реализовать "способ" покупок вместе с интернет-магазином, например, на битриксе. Там магазин готов, плюс ваше приложение, а все остальное взаимодействие осуществлять посредством SOAP-запросов.

Comment: Минус за битрикс не учите плохому

Comment: Это чем вам битрикс не нравится? Вы просто не умеете его "готовить"! Обоснуйте ваш минус

Comment: Нет архитектуры, кастыли, сплошные антипатерны, и извините за такое гавно платить? Это как купитт шестёрку когда вам мерседес бесплатно предлагают. Для веб разработчика который умеет верстать знает жс, чуть чуть пхп может и норм для бэкэнд это типичная говноцмс. Поверьте даже нехочу такое готовить, когда есть на порядки выше цмс к примеру магенту бесплатная, рабочая архитектура норм. П.С.высказвание не умете готовить странно похоже на фразу у меня все работает.

Comment: Все правильно вы понимаете! У меня нет к битриксу особых претензий, только одна - при работе свыше 10000 пользаков на сайте начинаются тормоза, которые они знают как решать, но специально не помогают, хотят еще деньжат. Поэтому пришлось городить костыли. А так просто все отлично работает в связке Firebase-Bitrix-Android.

Comment: Видите вы предлагаете городить кастыли, или платить за такие же кастыли...